# Visual Studio 2012 Editor Formatting

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, resharper

I am using Visual Studio 2012 to develop c# codes. Also using Resharper from JetBrains.

I was wondering if there is a way (or a plugin) that will allow me to define some custom formatting for my code.

```
public void foo()
{
   //do some stuff
}
```

One example is that I want to turn bold the member declaration like this:

**public void foo()**

I believe this would be easier to read.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this can be done with ReSharper or with any other Visual Studio extension I know of. If your code is well formatted and your methods short then it is quite easy to read their declarations without making them bold. If you just want to see a list of your methods then try using ReSharper's File Structure window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> or `Resharper`->`Windows`->`File Structure`). You could also try the Spade option in the [CodeMaid VS Extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/76293c4d-8c16-4f4a-aee6-21f83a571496). There are quite a few VS Extensions you can try out that may make your code easier to read.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to use the Resharper file structure.